# How to repair my aiogram code? Dispatcher problem

Tags: python, telegram, telegram-bot, dispatcher, aiogram

I want to have output "Hi" after entering "/Hello". It is working with

```
@dp.message_handler(commands=["Hello"])
```

but isn't with

```
def register_handlers_client(dp : Dispatcher):
    dp.register_message_handler(raspisanije, commands=["Hello"])
```

What's the problem?

```
TOKEN = 'TOKEN'
bot = Bot(token=TOKEN)
dp = Dispatcher(bot)


btn1 = KeyboardButton("/Hello")
mainMenu1 = ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard = True).add(btn1)

# @dp.message_handler(commands=["Hello"]) 
async def raspisanije(message: types.Message):
    await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, "Hi")

def register_handlers_client(dp : Dispatcher):
    dp.register_message_handler(raspisanije, commands=["Hello"])

if __name__ == "__main__":
    executor.start_polling(dp, skip_updates=True)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The register_handlers_client function is not being called.
You need to call it in the `if __name__ == "__main__":` so it becomes:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    register_handlers_client(dp)
    executor.start_polling(dp, skip_updates=True)
```